# postgresql create index on join table/nested query to make it fast

Tags: postgresql, jsp, indexing, postgresql-performance

postgresql(version 1.18.1) 
create index on join table/ or the way below is nested query

i have two table here:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    role        TEXT NOT NULL,
    age     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    state   TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    uid         INTEGER REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    pid         INTEGER REFERENCES products (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    quantity    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

right now i have the query to compute one state customer total sales

```
    select COALESCE(sum(quantity*price),0) as bigsum 
    from sales, users where users.role='customer' and users.id=sales.uid 
    and  state='New York'
"Aggregate  (cost=326562.33..326562.34 rows=1 width=8)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=9927.33..325582.33 rows=196000 width=8)"
"        Hash Cond: (sales.uid = users.id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on sales  (cost=0.00..163695.00 rows=10000000 width=12)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9682.33..9682.33 rows=19600 width=4)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=424.32..9682.33 rows=19600 width=4)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (state = 'New York'::text)"
"                    Filter: (role = 'customer'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_user_state  (cost=0.00..419.43 rows=19600 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: (state = 'New York'::text)"
```

where this give me 7940 ms.
right now the sales table 10 million entries and users table 1000,000 entries
i want it faster, how to do this?
the index right now i have:

```
CREATE INDEX index_sales_user ON sales (uid);
CREATE INDEX index_user_id  ON users (id);
CREATE INDEX index_user_role_state ON users(role) WHERE role = 'customer';
CREATE INDEX index_user_state ON users (state);
CREATE INDEX index_users_role ON users (role) where role='customer';
```

i got the result
**Total query runtime: 7334 ms.
1 row retrieved.**

```
 select COALESCE(sum(quantity*price),0) as bigsum 
 from sales  where uid in (select id from users where role='customer' and  state='New York')

"Aggregate  (cost=217188.73..217188.74 rows=1 width=8)"
"  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=9927.33..216033.22 rows=231101 width=8)"
"        Hash Cond: (sales.uid = users.id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on sales  (cost=0.00..163695.00 rows=10000000 width=12)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=9682.33..9682.33 rows=19600 width=4)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=424.32..9682.33 rows=19600 width=4)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (state = 'New York'::text)"
"                    Filter: (role = 'customer'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_user_state  (cost=0.00..419.43 rows=19600 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: (state = 'New York'::text)"
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info, follow the advice there, and update your question based on that. Show exact PostgreSQL version, `explain analyze` results, etc.

Comment: And what indexes do you have? You need at least an index on sales.uid and want to play with indexes on users.role and users.state

Comment: update the five index i have created

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using PostgreSQL version 1.18.1. Check again. (Current version is 9.3, and 9.4 is in beta.) You're probably looking at the version number for pgAdminIII.

Comment: `->  Seq Scan on sales  (cost=0.00..163695.00 rows=10000000 width=12)` The plan generator is assuming an almost catesian product here; did you run `VACUUM analyze users; VACUUM ANALYZE sales;` after creting the indexes ? BTW(stylistic) : 1) use JOIN syntax 2) user aliases 3) replace `x.a IN (select b... from y)` by `EXISTS (select 1 from y where y.b = x.a ...)` 
`

Comment: use join or EXISTS (select 1 from y where y.b = x.a ...), which is better?

Comment: what do you mean by  run VACUUM analyze users

Comment: version is 9.3.just check